# How can I get sudo commands to use the settings in /root/.bashrc

Tags: bash, debian, sudo

I have customised `.bashrc` with a number of alias, specifically `ll` and `export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'`

Unfortunately this does not work when used with `sudo`, so I also modified `/root/.bashrc`, but this seems to have made no difference.

`sudo env` shows `HOME=/root` and `SHELL=/bin/bash`

How can I get `sudo` commands to use the settings in `/root/.bashrc`?

I understand that this happens only when `bash` is executed interactively, so I am open to any other suggestions as to how to customise.

Comment: @daniel-gelling - I've always felt like this Q is a XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. The title implies they want anything out of `/root/.bashrc` but really what the Q is after is the aliases from this file - this is not possible per this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases.

Comment: @slm What i'm after is adding a method to bashrc - as I've done in my personal .bashrc file as well as the .bashrc file for root to "disable" the `-r` option for `crontab`: `crontab () { [[ $@ =~ -[iel]*r ]] && echo '"r" not allowed' || command crontab "$@" ;}`. This works when logged in as either user, however when I execute `sudo crontab -r` it still executes.

Comment: @DanielGelling  - see if my answer works for you scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to those who answered, who prompted me to read `man sudo` more carefully.

`sudo -s` **If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.**

This interactive shell uses `/root/.bashrc` and thus includes my customisations.

It does require the command be entered separately, but this is OK.

Answer (score 6):

`sudo` runs an executable, not a shell command. So it doesn't know about aliases. If you run `sudo ls`, that's like `sudo /bin/ls`, it doesn't use any `ls` alias that you may have.

You can cause `sudo ls` to expand the alias by putting the following in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

Note the trailing space — that tells the shell to continue alias expansion with the word that comes after `sudo`. Beware that expanding aliases after sudo may not always be a good idea, it depends what kinds of aliases you have.

Furthermore sudo removes most variables from the environment. This won't affect an alias like `alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'`, because that's a shell variable used by the shell while it's expanding the command (and exporting it from `.bashrc` serves no purpose). But it would affect variables that are used by the command, such as `LS_COLORS`. You can configure sudo to keep certain environment variables by editing its configuration: run `visudo` and add the line

```
Defaults env_keep += "LS_COLORS"
```

With these settings, `sudo ll` will give the colors you're used to.

Alternatively, you can run a root shell with `sudo -s`. This shell will load its configuration file (`~/.bashrc` for bash). Depending on how sudo is configured, this may keep `HOME` set to your home directory, or change it to `/root`. You can force the home directory to be set to root's with `sudo -Hs`; conversely, to keep the original home directory, run `sudo env HOME="$HOME" bash`.

Answer (score 4):

### Background

I've always felt like this question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The title implies they want anything out of `/root/.bashrc` but really what the question is after is the aliases from this file - this is widely believed to not be possible per this - [Why doesn't my Bash script recognize aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases).

It's basically by design that your aliases will not get picked up in `sudo` and in other places because they're not portable, and this is my opinion on them as well.

Anything that's in the user's environment should not be assumed by scripts and any software that may run on a given box. But I realize that there are scenarios where there might be some aliases in a given user account's `$HOME/.bashrc` that others might want to leverage in interactive scenarios.

To that end you can simply tell the Bash interpreter to expand any aliases that it finds during the login process outside of the normal shell behaviors that you run into when using `sudo`.

### Example

#### Setup

To set things up I've added the following aliases, environment variables, and functions to my root user's `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.bash_profile` files.

```
$ grep smurf ~/.bashrc
alias brc_smurf='echo "ran alias from /root/.bashrc"'
export brc_smurf_env='var from /root/.bashrc'
bpf_smurf_func() { echo 'ran func from /root/.bash_profile'; }

$ grep smurf ~/.bash_profile
alias bpf_smurf='echo "ran alias from /root/.bash_profile"'
export bpf_smurf_env='var from /root/.bash_profile'
brc_smurf_func() { echo 'ran func from /root/.bashrc'; }
```

Without doing anything neither of these work (no surprises):

```
$ sudo brc_smurf
sudo: brc_smurf: command not found

$ sudo bpf_smurf
sudo: bpf_smurf: command not found
```

We see that the `alias` command shows no aliases when run in `sudo`:

```
$ sudo alias
$
```

This behavior is your hint that you shouldn't expect aliases to be accessible. But we carry on...

#### Step #1 - aliases visible

If we run `bash -ci` we can induce Bash to at least read our `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
$ sudo bash -ci 'alias' | grep smurf
alias brc_smurf='echo "ran alias from /root/.bashrc"'
```

Cool, so maybe we can run it?

```
$ sudo bash -ci 'alias; brc_smurf'
bash: alias; brc_smurf: No such file or directory
```

#### Step #2 - `shopt -s expand_aliases`

Nope. Again this is by design, we're doing something we're not suppose to be doing, so there's a number of "safeties" that we have to disable. the other "safety" is Bash.

```
$ sudo bash -ci 'shopt -s expand_aliases; alias; brc_smurf'
alias brc_smurf='echo "ran alias from /root/.bashrc"'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
ran alias from /root/.bashrc
```

Here we can see our message from `/root/.bashrc`, we've successfully executed the root user's alias `brc_smurf`.

#### Step #3 - what about env vars?

If you're using the method shown above these should now work as well.

```
$ sudo bash -ci 'shopt -s expand_aliases; brc_smurf; echo $brc_smurf_env'
ran alias from /root/.bashrc
var from /root/.bashrc
```

#### Step #4 - what about functions?

These works too as expected:

```
$ sudo bash -ci 'shopt -s expand_aliases; brc_smurf; echo $brc_smurf_env;brc_smurf_func'
ran alias from /root/.bashrc
var from /root/.bashrc
ran func from /root/.bashrc
```

#### TLDR;

You can do this to get access to environment variables + aliases from `/root/.bashrc`:

```
$ sudo bash -ci 'shopt -s expand_aliases; <cmds>'
```

#### Take aways

This method enables the contents of `/root/.bashrc`, it does not pick up the contents of `/root/.bash_profile`.

#### References

- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
- [Why does sudo ignore aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148545/why-does-sudo-ignore-aliases)
- [Why doesn't my Bash script recognize aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases)

Comment: Yep, even though there are some minor differences between them, let's not go into detail here ;-). Anyways, could you help me with the situation I stated in the comments of the question: using functions in `.bashrc` with sudo; specifically removing the `-r` option from `crontab`?

Comment: Okay, but this would mean that I'd have to run: `sudo bash -ci 'alias; shopt -s expand_aliases; echo $brc_smurf_env'` instead of a simple `sudo echo $brc_smurf_env`?

Comment: You can remove the `alias`, that was simply to show them, you'd need to do `sudo bash -ci 'shopt -s expand_aliases; <cmds>'`

Comment: That would be a lot of typing just to edit my crontab for root. Let me create an alias for it :-P

Comment: @DanielGelling - yup, welcome to all the fun down in the shell bowels.

Comment: @DanielGelling - the other approach is shell functions, those are exportable so you might want to reformulate your plan of attack.

Comment: Worth noting that it's *always* a major naughtiness to to rely on external aliases when writing scripts.  Aliases are intended to assist usability for humans.  The key problem here is that it breaks portability of scripts.  Having said that, functions are fine, and if you really, really must use aliases you define them inline within your script, with good explanatory comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of settings in the /etc/sudoers file specifically or setting up an environment for when sudo commands are run (eg. Making sure the PATH only has trusted locations) but depending on what you're hoping to get out of this you might not be able to do what you're after if it involves running actual commands in a shell to set up the environment. Sudoing specifically doesn't give you a root login shell so it won't set up a regular profile for you.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You can use `sudo -i` to run a **function** defined `/root/.bashrc` (but not an alias) and also have access to variables exported from that file:

```
sudo -i command arguments
```

Aliases don't work there, though, but you can easily convert them to functions if you'd like to make them available to `sudo -i`.

Read on for full analysis and more details.

---

There are a few problems here, some in how sudo works and some in how bash itself works...

By default, `sudo` will only look for commands and will bypass the shell, so simply running `sudo ll` will only work if there's an `ll` executable in one of the directories in `$PATH`. So, in order to use aliases (or functions) you need to make sure a shell is invoked as part of the process.

One way would be to run something like `sudo sh` or `sudo bash`, though modern `sudo` (I'm testing this on sudo 1.8.19p1) has options `-s` and `-i` for that purpose.

So one try would be something like `sudo -s ll` (which is equivalent to `sudo bash -c 'll'`, assuming your `$SHELL` is Bash, which seems to be the case based on the `rcfile` you mentioned.) But that doesn't work either, since it starts the shell in a non-interactive, non-login mode, which doesn't read any of its startup files. It's essentially the same as if you write a shell script and use `#!/bin/bash` to run it. The aliases (and functions) you have in your `~/.bashrc` won't be accessible from that script...

So next is the `-i` option, which creates a login shell. That's more promising, since it *will* read your startup files! And yet, `sudo -i ll` (equivalent to `sudo bash -l -c 'll'`) will still not work. So how is that possible, given it *did* read the definition of the `ll` alias?

Well, the next explanation here is that, by default, bash will not expand aliases, except when the shell is interactive... This shell started by `sudo -i` (or `bash -l`) is a *login* shell, but still not interactive.

So the next step is to get an *interactive* shell, which then **works**:

```
sudo bash -i -c 'll'
```

(Having both *login* and *interactive* is also fine, of course, `bash -l -i -c ...` will work.)

Another alternative is to keep using a *login* shell (non-interactive) but ask it explicitly to expand aliases, so this will also work:

```
sudo bash -l -O expand_aliases -c 'll'
```

(The case where bash was *interactive* didn't need a *login* shell, since that is enough to read the initialization files, but this one needs `-l` to read them.)

These are fairly long command lines... And they also require that you quote the whole shell command, so if you're calling an alias with arguments, you'll have to turn all that into a string... So it's kind of clumsy to use...

Note that earlier I was talking about aliases and *functions*... That was on purpose, since functions are actually a lot more convenient here. You don't need anything special (such as having an interactive shell, or setting a specific option) to execute functions on a shell, as long as you're sourcing their definition.

So if you defined `ll` as a *function* instead of an alias, you'd be able to use it directly with sudo's `-i` shortcut:

```
sudo -i ll
```

And if you have a longer command-line, with arguments, you could pass them directly here too:

```
sudo -i ll -C -R /etc
```

(Compare to `sudo bash -i -c 'll -C -R /etc'`.)

Functions are also a lot more flexible and typically easier to maintain... It's usually easy to convert an alias into a function, the only caveat is to always use `"$@"` where you'd expect extra arguments to be taken (typically at the end of the alias.)

For example, this alias:

```
alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
```

Could be turned into this function:

```
ll () {
    ls $LS_OPTIONS -l "$@"
}
```

They are, for most purposes, equivalent. And, as mentioned before, the function should be accessible directly from `sudo -i`, so that's an added bonus.

I hope you find this answer and explanation helpful!

Comment: DV - I don't feel like this is improving the situation anymore than what's already here either.

Comment: @slm I do think my answer is adding something, since no previous answer mentioned the form `sudo -i command arguments` to be able to run *functions* from `/root/.bashrc` and have exported variables available. But I see how my answer was perhaps too long and that info was somewhat buried in there... So I added a TL;DR to summarize it (while still keeping the technical details of the investigation around.) Please take another look.