# Expand (certain) aliases from within sudo bash function

Tags: bash, sudo, alias

There are two things I want: 1) I want that if I keep using `sudo` often that it never asks me for my password by updating my cached credentials every time I type `sudo`, 2) That I can use (certain) aliases while using sudo.

In order to update ones credentials one has to execute `sudo -v` (without command).

For example, I do not have a `/usr/bin/vi`. I do have a `/usr/bin/nvim`. I have an alias:

```
alias vi='/usr/bin/nvim'
```

So, if I type as non-root:

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

Then I want that is executed:

```
sudo -v
sudo /usr/bin/nvim /etc/fstab
```

I tried to achieve this by creating the bash function:

```
function sudo()
{
  command sudo -v
  command sudo "$@"
}
```

However, this results in the error:

```
sudo: vi: command not found
```

In other words, the alias `vi` is not expanded from the `"$@"` inside the `sudo` function.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148545/117549 ?

Comment: Ditto. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148548/108618) adjusted to your requirements: `alias sudo='sudo -v; sudo '`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Not working. `sudo: vi: command not found`

Comment: I tried a billion things and absolutely nothing works :/.

Comment: The alias I gave you works for me in Bash 4.4.12. Did you type it? or did you paste? Maybe you missed the space just before the closing quote. It's crucial.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, my fault. I was experimenting so I think I had 'vi' defined as function at that moment! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```bsh
function sudo()
{
  command sudo -v
  if [[ $(type -t "$1") == "alias" ]]; then
    set -- bash -ic "$(alias "$1"); $(printf "%q " "$@")"
  fi
  # what am I about to execute
  printf "%q " sudo "$@"; echo
  # and do it
  command sudo "$@"
}
```

Comment: Did you test it? I get errors: `bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'`, `bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`.

Comment: OK, this should fix it. The root shell needs to be interactive.

Comment: Awesome, this works! So, the trick here is that you expand the alias(es) in an "interactive" shell by printing "$@" to printf using %q. I don't think I saw that trick anywhere yet! Clever!

Comment: The `$(alias "$1")` part adds your alias to the root shell (there was an error here in the last iteration). Then the `$(printf ...)` part adds (into the root shell script) the function arguments to be executed. I use `%q` because otherwise we quickly get into quoting hell.

Answer (score 0):

Although Kamil's `alias sudo='sudo -v; sudo '` works equally well as glenn's answer, namely expanding the first word after sudo if that is an alias; it could be seen as a security issue to "blindly" expand aliases.

In the light of a possible configuration for `visudo` of

```
/etc/sudoers:

Defaults editor=/usr/bin/nvim, !env_editor
```

which ignores the `EDITOR` environment variable (equally a security risk) and
always opens `/etc/sudoers` with `/usr/bin/nvim` one could use the following
bash function as well (assume you're in the habbit of typing `vi` as your editor):

```
~/.bashrc:

sudo ()
{ 
    command sudo -nv 2> /dev/null;
    COMMAND="$1";
    shift;
    [ "$COMMAND" = "vi" ] && COMMAND="/usr/bin/nvim";
    command sudo "$COMMAND" "$@"
}
```

which likewise will then allow

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

but always use `/usr/bin/nvim`, without expanding an alias.

Also note the use of `sudo -nv` as opposed to `sudo -v`. This is to avoid the latter asking for a password when the real command doesn't require one.